# Validation_data and Validation_split

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

So I have a GRU model that predict output power. For the training data I have a csv file which has data from 2018, while for my testting data it is a different csv file which has data from 2019.

I just had to short questions.

1. Since I'm using 2 different csv files one for testing and one for training, I do not need to `train_test_split`?
2. When it comes to model.fit, I really don't know the difference between  `Validation_data` and  `Validation_split` and which one should I use?

I have tested these 3 lines seperately, the 2nd and 3rd line give me the same exact results , while the first gives me way lower  `val_loss`.

Thank you.

```
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=25, validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])  
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])
history=model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=256, epochs=25, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), validation_split=0.1, verbose=1, callbacks=[TensorBoardColabCallback(tbc)])
```

Comment: Please learn to read documentations. Everything you ask is already answered in the Keras documentation for model.fit. 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit

Answer (score 6):

1. You can do what you want, yes you can use one file to train and one to validate. But you could also merge them then use `train_test_split` if you wish. However, I would recommend you to merge them as you have data from different periods of time, there may be differences.
2. Using `validation_data` means you are providing the training set and validation set yourself, whereas using `validation_split` means you only provide a training set and keras splits it into a training set and a validation set (with the validation set being `validation_split` times the size of the training set)

Comment: @ThmasSchillaci Regarding 1. Do you mean to concatinate both csv files into one csv file? I'm trying to predict wind turbine power output, so the differences in values makes it more relasitic? I thought the purpose of the test data is to see if my training data(2018) predicts the values correct which is (2019). Regarding 2. since I'm using 2019 data for testing then it makes more sense to use the 2nd line of code in the post? I'm really sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you want a model that can generalize as much as possible, then you want to import the two csv files and merge them using python (yes you can re-export the result to a csv file if you want). If you want to study the similarity between the two periods of time, then you should train it on the first file and validate it on the second one. Regarding 2., I think so too.

Comment: So in reality I can jsut use 2018 data without using 2019 and train_test_split 2018 data only? Regarding 2. , I tested it with only 1 layer and 5 epochs to see the difference, the val_loss for the first code was 0.0028 after 5 epochs and the second code gave me 0.0168, which is quite significant. I'm really sorry for asking too many questions.

Comment: Yes you can. Regarding 2. the first code uses a split_ratio of 10% whereas `train_test_split` uses 25% by default, this can change a lot of things, including the value of your `val_loss`

Comment: So if If i use train_test_split 25% for example, and 10% in validation_split, I'm using 35% in total?

Comment: You can't use both, the doc states: `validation_data` will override `validation_split`: https://keras.io/models/sequential/#fit

Comment: Yes I have just read that and disregarded the third line in my opening post. Thank you very much!